# FlutterFlow Custom Widget Error - Implementing flutter_map package from pub.dev

Tags: flutter, maps, fluttermap, flutterflow, flutter-mapbox-gl

**Summary:**
I'm attempting to build a custom widget in FlutterFlow using the flutter_map package from pub.dev. I think I'm getting pretty close to having the basic build working, but it is throwing an error that I don't understand how to fix (see the error below). This error is coming from the "layers" parameter within the custom widget near the bottom.

I've watched a few tutorials about implementing this package into a Flutter app, and they're able to use the "layers" parameter without issue. Here's an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZwrcOTxDJI&t=391s

Plz help :') I am more than happy to supply further information if what I've provided here is insufficient.

**Error:**
"The named parameter 'layers' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'layers'."

**Custom Code"**

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as ltlng;

class FlutterMapTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterMapTest({Key? key, this.width, this.height, this.layers})
      : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  _FlutterMapTestState createState() => _FlutterMapTestState();
}

class _FlutterMapTestState extends State<FlutterMapTest> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      FlutterMap(
          mapController: MapController(),
          options: MapOptions(),
          children: [],
          layers: TileLayer(
            urlTemplate:
                "***",
            additionalOptions: {
              'accessToken':
                  "***",
            },
          ))
    ]);
  }
}
```

**Pubspec Dependencies**
flutter_map: ^4.0.0

I tried creating a parameter called "layers", added that parameter into the code, but it didn't resolve anything. That was honestly a shot in the dark.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this in the future, the resolution for this was to remove the 'layers' parameter and move the TileLayer block inside of the 'children' parameter.

I had to rewrite a bit of the code to do it, but I've managed to get a functioning dynamic Mapbox map built into my FlutterFlow app.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Chase. Please add this as an answer to the question. Would be good if you could also add the code in there. It will help people and will also allow people to upvote your answer. There is nothing wrong in marking your own answer as the answer.

Comment: Cool, I'll do that. Didn't know it was possible to answer my own question until just now lol @jack

Comment: Really cool, thanks, Chase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this in the future, the resolution for this was to remove the 'layers' parameter and move the TileLayer block inside of the 'children' parameter. I had to rewrite a bit of the code to do it, but I've managed to get a functioning dynamic Mapbox map built into my FlutterFlow app.

Here's the updated code:

```
class _FlutterMapWidgetState extends State<FlutterMapWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: widget.width,
        height: widget.height,
        child: FlutterMap(
          mapController: MapController(),
          options: MapOptions(
            center: ltlng.LatLng(34.6, -92.4),
            zoom: 7.0,
            minZoom: 7.0,
          ),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate:
                  "***",
              additionalOptions: {
                'accessToken':
                    "***",
              }, //additionalOptions
            ) //TileLayer
          ], //children
        ) //FlutterMap
        );
  }
}
```